# Mindstorms: Installation of NXT2.0f3 patch for Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Tags: osx-lion, lego-mindstorms

Looking for installation help with NXT2.0f3 patch for mindstorms NXT 2.0 software on iMac w/ Lion 10.7.3. Base software installation from CD works fine (with some minor glitches once the NXT software is running that I can live with for now); however, applying the NXT2.0f3 patch (so-called Mac software fix downloaded from Lego) prevents NXT application startup. On application startup, I get an alert box with

> "Error Code: 1003" stating that a required file is broken. The program then quits. No useful information (like a filename) there.

Mindstorms phone support wasn't helpful. Did reinstalls five times with different combinations of 32-bit and 64-bit mode OSX. Also tried installing driver package from CD to repair installation (after patch was applied), but no luck.

Has anyone got this working, or run into the same problem and have a solution?